# Solving Simultaneous Equations with logarithms (require all steps)

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

I would really appreciate a full solution with all working out to the following simultaneous equations, as I can't seem to arrive at the same answer as a text book on part of a question.

The equations are:

$$ V_1 = A \ln r_1 + B$$
$$ V_2 = A \ln r_2 + B$$

The answer in the book is:

$$ A = \frac{V_2 - V_1}{\ln r_2 - \ln r_1} = \frac{V_2 - V_1}{\ln (r_2/r_1)} $$

$$ B = \frac{V_1 \ln r_2 - V_2 \ln r_1}{\ln (r_2/r_1)} $$

Inserting these into the general equation $$ V(r) = A \ln r + B$$ gives:

$$ V(r) = \frac{V_2 - V_1}{\ln (r_2/r_1)} \ln r \ + \frac{V_1 \ln r_2 - V_2 \ln r_1}{\ln (r_2/r_1)} $$

$$ V(r) = \frac{V_2 \ln(r/r_1) - V_1 \ln(r/r_2)}{\ln (r_2/r_1)} $$

Thank you

Comment: What is wrong with the answer in the book?  It is a simple solution to a simple problem.  Your approach seems to be unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: What do you mean? The last line is the book answer, I don't understand how they got there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equations are 
$$V_1=A\ln r_1+B\tag1$$
$$V_2=A\ln r_2+B\tag2$$
Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ we obtain
$$V_2-V_1=A(\ln r_2-\ln r_1)$$
$$\implies A=\frac{V_2 - V_1}{\ln r_2 - \ln r_1} = \frac{V_2 - V_1}{\ln (r_2/r_1)}$$
Pluging this result into $(1)$ we get
$$\begin{align}
V_1&=\frac{V_2 - V_1}{\ln (r_2/r_1)}\ln r_1 + B \\
\implies B&=V_1-\frac{V_2 - V_1}{\ln (r_2/r_1)}\ln r_1 \\
&= \frac{V_1 \ln(r_2/r_1)-(V_2-V_1)\ln r_1}{\ln (r_2/r_1)} \\
&=\frac{V_1\ln r_2-V_1\ln r_1-V_2\ln r_1+V_1\ln r_1}{\ln (r_2/r_1)} \\
&=\frac{V_1\ln r_2 - V_2\ln r_1}{\ln (r_2/r_1)} \\
\end{align}$$

Inserting these into the equation $V(r)=A\ln r+B$ gives
$$\begin{align}
V(r) &= \frac{V_2 - V_1}{\ln (r_2/r_1)} \ln r \ + \frac{V_1 \ln r_2 - V_2 \ln r_1}{\ln (r_2/r_1)} \\
&=\frac{V_2\ln r - V_1\ln r+V_1 \ln r_2 - V_2 \ln r_1}{\ln (r_2/r_1)} \\
&=\frac{V_2(\ln r - \ln r_1) - V_1(\ln r - \ln r_2)}{\ln (r_2/r_1)} \\
&=\frac{V_2\ln (r/r_1) - V_1\ln (r/r_2)}{\ln (r_2/r_1)}
\end{align}$$
as desired.

Comment: That's great, thank you. Much appreciated, and makes sense.